# How can I install Ganglia in Windows and how can I establish connection from my Java application?

Tags: java, monitoring, dropwizard, ganglia, codahale-metrics

I have integrated Java Metrics in my code and now I need to display the results in Ganglia web interface. I went through the Ganglia page where Windows support is specified but there installer is not provided anywhere to be downloaded http://ganglia.info/?p=42  And the download page https://sourceforge.net/projects/ganglia/files/ganglia%20monitoring%20core/3.7.1/ only provides a Linux file.

Would really appreciate if someone who has already done this could provide me with the steps of Ganglia Windows installation and how I can connect my JVM instance to the web interface.